# Runtime error in sorting with custom comparator

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, runtime-error, stdstring

I am trying to sort a vector of strings based on a custom comparator function -:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
std::string ToString( const T& obj )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << obj;
    return ss.str();
}

bool comp( string num1, string num2 )
{
    bool swapped = false;

    if ( num2.size() > num1.size() )
    {
        swap( num1, num2 );
        swapped = true;
    }

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;

    while ( i < num1.size() && j < num2.size() )
    {
        if ( num1[i] > num2[j] )
        {
            return !swapped;
        }
        else if ( num1[i] < num2[j] )
        {
            return swapped;
        }

        i++;
        j++;
    }

    j = 0;

    while ( i < num1.size() && j < num1.size() )
    {
        if ( num1[i] > num1[j] )
        {
            return !swapped;
        }
        else if ( num1[i] < num1[j] )
        {
            return swapped;
        }

        i++;
        j++;
    }

    return true;
}

string largestNumber( vector<int>& nums )
{
    vector<string> numsString( nums.size() );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < numsString.size(); i++ )
    {
        numsString[i] = ToString( nums[i] );
    }

    string result;
    sort( numsString.begin(), numsString.end(), comp );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < numsString.size(); i++ )
    {
        result += numsString[i];
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    // Works okay if the size of vector is less than 17
    vector<int> nums( 17, 0 );
    largestNumber( nums );
}
```

I am using TDM-GCC 4.9.2 with `-std=c++14` flag on Windows 7 64-bit.

I am getting a runtime error every time the size of the input vector is greater than 16.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't know. Whenever I run the program, there is a dialog box saying *`<exe> has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program.`*

Comment: No. I haven't used any before, and I don't know how to use one.

Comment: The definition of ToString may be useful.

Comment: You ought to use a custom compare function that acts reasonably.  The most important should be that A<A returns false (in your code it is typically true).  But also when A<B is true you should not have B<A also true, which will occur in many cases in your code.  But I don't know the internals of **sort** well enough to predict how it would malfunction will an unstable comparison function.  So I'm not sure this is your major problem

Comment: After finding num1 and num2 are equal up to the length of the shorter one, your code appears to compare the rest (if any) of num1 to the earlier part of itself (not to any part of num2).  Was that really your intent?

Comment: Not sure what the intent of the compare function is, but I'm sure it can be done much simpler.

Comment: Most (maybe all) of the problems would be fixed by changing the return true at the bottom to return false.  That would cover the case where num1==num2 perfectly, and I think covers the other cases where the existing code says A<B and B<A.

Comment: the while loops seem to be unnecessary

Comment: @JSF The problem got fixed by  changing `return true;` to `return false;` instead. But I don't understand the reason. Could you please explain ?

Comment: The compare operation for sort is supposed to represent something that acts abstractly like a less-than operator.  It does not need to represent the < relationship, but it does need to be self consistent in ways that < is self consistent.  Such as: A<A is never true and when A<B is true, B<A must be false.  When num1 and num2 are "equivalent" in your comparison (a broader relationship that includes the equality case) your code reaches that final return.  For equivalent values, a less-than relationship must return false.

Comment: The other way to look at this is focus on the fact that a valid compare routine might return false for both A,B and B,A but must not return true for both of those.  The cases where your code reaches that final return are exactly the cases where it does not matter whether it received A,B or B,A (If it got to the bottom for A,B it would get to the bottom for B,A).  So a valid compare routine cannot return true for such cases.

Comment: @JSF Interesting.. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All elements in your `vector<string> numsString` end up having the same value `0` converted into string:

```
vector<int> nums( 17, 0 );
//                    ^
```

And, in your `comp` function, you are not checking if the numbers are equal. 
Add that as well at the top of the function:

```
if (num1 == num2) return false;
```

Comment: That check at the top whether the strings are equal would just waste time and cover up **part** of a more fundamental problem.  The overall comparison should avoid all cases where both A<B is true and B<A is true.  In the course of making such a correction, you would get A<A false without needing an extra test for ==